# Horizontally centring divs of varying numbers

Tags: html, css, center

So I'm trying to make a page with a few wide divs that are stacked vertically down the page. Within each div are a number of other divs that I'm trying to centre and distribute horizontally. The issue is that not all parent divs are going to have the same number of horizontally-distributed divs within them, e.g. some have 3 and some 4. I want to be able to have these smaller divs grouped next to each other, with the same amount of space on either side of the group. Here is my code:

```css
#prod-container {
  max-width: 920px;
  margin: 26px auto 0px auto;
  background-color: #000066;
}
.prod-mod {
  width: 225px;
  /*border:1px solid #EDEDED;*/
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="prod-container">
  <h2 class="cls-title">Classic West Coast® 11.6</h2>
  <div class="prod-mod">
    <img src="img.jpg">
    <p class="cls-subtitle">Traditional Rowing Model</p>
  </div>
  <div class="prod-mod">
    <img src="img.jpg">
    <p class="cls-subtitle">Slide Seat Sculling Model</p>
  </div>
  <div class="prod-mod">
    <img src="img.jpg">
    <p class="cls-subtitle">Sailing Model</p>
  </div>
  <div class="prod-mod">
    <img src="img.jpg">
    <p class="cls-subtitle">Lifeguard Boat</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

That's an example containing 4 divs, but there will be others with only 3. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the `flex` display model, namely with `justify-content: space-around;`:

```css
div {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
div div {
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  background: beige;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```